# Dropped AC adapter on laptop with lid closed from a height of about 10cm

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair, repair, physical-damage

The adapter weighs less than 300g. There are no visible damage on the lid. The screen also seems fine. If there are no damage now, is it safe to say the risks of getting issues in the future is the same as it would be if I had not dropped the adapter on the lid?

Thanks.

Comment: There is absolutely no way we can determine if your hardware has been damaged.  If it’s functional, that’s a good sign, if you don’t have the expertise to look at it take it to an expert.  This is the type of thing anyone with the knowledge required to determine something like this, must have physical access to the device which isn’t possible on the internet

Comment: Thanks for the information. At what point, even if you do not see any symptoms, would you take it to an expert? That is, how heavy and from what height a drop of something is on your laptop, would you be concerned?

Comment: 10cm is nothing, my entire laptop has been dropped to the floor from a height of half a meter about a dozen times. Also there is an air gap between the panel glass and the lid plastic in most cases, there was most likely 0 impact on the glass

Comment: Half a dozen half meter drops sounds pretty bad. Its impressive laptops can withstand that. What make is your laptop? An air gap sounds like it will help.

Comment: an older dell latitude, got it as a refurb, it gets knocked off the couch a lot, luckily I installed an SSD or drops like that would have killed a regular drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

For real though, most laptops are strong enough to withstand that kind of impact. I would be really surprised if there was any damage done.

Edit: Looking back at this answer, it is too short. Please allow me to elaborate:

LCD screens break often due to impact, but when they do it's immediately obvious by looking at the screen. There will be a large black spot, or verticle / horizontal lines that shouldn't be there. They're generally like a piece of glass, it's either broken or not broken, there's no space in between. Other components you may want to check after something has impacted the top half of your laptop are:

1. Camera (facetime camera, etc.)
2. Microphone
3. LEDs and other decorative electronics
4. Wifi reception (because your wifi antenna is most likely wrapped all the way around your screen.

If all of those things are still working properly and the screen does not have any large black spots, verticle / horizontal lines, or other visible damage then there is no reason to believe that the computer was damaged at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can't upvote due to being a novice, but will do so when I can. As for best answer, I would like to get as much opinion as possible first.